# Bind <Cmd-S> in Vim

Tags: terminal

Is it possible to map  to save in vim in a standard terminal? I know how to set it in my vimrc but am not sure if it is possible to pass it from terminal to vim instead of attempting to save the terminal.

Comment: Would [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) be an option ? It uses cmd+s for saving. And you can start it from terminal with `mvim`.

Comment: I am using vim with tmux so macvim wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should be able to set up a key mapping in your .vimrc file so that when you press command - S it maps to :w  Also here is something else to go on that you can modify as well [Map Ctrl-S to save current or new files](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-S_to_save_current_or_new_files)

- First thing is to reassign the the Command - S functionality for the Application. Do this in the Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts System Preference Pane.

For example, you will want to add in a new Application Short cut for the Terminal app, then map to the Menu title "Export Text As..." to another keyboard command something that you don't use, e.g. control - s or etc. should be fine.

- Next stop mac terminal from trying to interpret Cmd-s by ... **(still working on this I asked a separate question for a solution [Allow the Terminal.app to pass command key  based keystrokes to terminal programs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49222/how-to-stop-the-terminal-from-not-passing-command-keystrokes-to-terminal-prgrams) )**
- Set up the mapping in the .vimrc file to map the command or meta and s  keys to the :write function.

Something such as this noted below* you can add to you .vimrc:

```
:map <M-s> :w<kEnter>  "Works in normal mode, must press Esc first"
:imap <M-s> <Esc>:w<kEnter>i "Works in insert mode, saves and puts back in insert mode"
```

*This was verified working on the X11 terminal on OS X Lion.

Comment: Thanks, will keep an eye on that thread to see if there is a way to get cmd-s passed to the app.

Answer (score 1):

For people still coming across this, I've written up an inverse of **MrDaniel**'s solution (that is, mapping *any* MacVim / system-wide ⌘-sequence to command-line `vim`), and [posted it to his other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/172228/15184). It's more complex than his solution, but then allows you to (with some effort) remap *any* ⌘-sequence into *any* command-line program.

It works well for me, and I hope it can help you too. <3