# Allow the Terminal.app to pass command key  based keystrokes to terminal programs

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, x11

I want to allow programs running in the terminal the ability to interpret the keyboard short cut  <kbd>Cmd</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd>

I have already Remapped the Terminals' default binding of  <kbd>Cmd</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> to  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> via the Keyboard System Preferences in OS X Lion, so this has stopped the Terminal App itself from interpreting that key press, e.g. the save dialog no longer comes up when pressing  <kbd>Cmd</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> . However something is still grabbing the key input before any terminal program can.

For example when running bash typing   <kbd>Cmd</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> in the X11.app terminal results in:

```
$s
```

being printed to the screen.

When I perform the same  <kbd>Cmd</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> in the Terminal.app nothing is printed and the OS plays an Error Sound. I am not really sure why the keystroke is not making it to the terminal as expected, how do I allow  <kbd>Cmd</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> to pass thru.

**For more information on what / why  I am trying to do this see question [Bind <Cmd-S> in Vim](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49178/bind-cmd-s-in-vim)**

Answer (score 2):

I have similar desires to yours. I solved it using a system-level modifier-key re-bind.

(Of course, this is a mess; but I find it worth it to maintain my MacVim-trained hybrid of OS-wide controls (save, new, copy, paste) within command-line `vim`s.)

Here's how I did it:

1. Install [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/), which is a *very*, very powerful program (and an essential part of any poweruser's / programmer's OS X installation, IMHO)
2. Enable **“Command_L to Control_L (only in Terminal)”**:
3. Map <kbd>⌃</kbd>-prefixed controls matching whichever MacVim commands you're most used-to in command-line `vim`. For instance, to support <kbd>⌘S</kbd>,

   ```
   noremap  <silent> <C-S>    :update<CR>
   vnoremap <silent> <C-S>    <C-C>:update<CR>
   inoremap <silent> <C-S>    <C-O>:update<CR>
   ```
4. Restore expected <kbd>⌘</kbd>-sequences for Terminal.app itself, by special-casing them in System Preferences. For instance, if you want <kbd>⌘N</kbd> to still control Terminal tabs, instead of mapping it to `vim` files, try:

   Now, anything you *don't* add in this list, will be passed through verbatim to command-line `vim` (and, of course, any other command-line program you use.)

---

## Caveats

This approach has several *further* subtle downsides, that I want to hilight for anyone considering taking it (as I do):

- <kbd>⌘␣</kbd> will no longer map to the system-wide Spotlight. (I've an [open issue](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner/issues/347) on Karabiner, and will come back here once I have a stopgap solution.)
- For reasons I can't ascertain, even with the <kbd>⌃W</kbd> exclusions set up in System Preferences, the tab-closing behaviour of Terminal.app changes with this setup: <kbd>⌘W</kbd> will close individual tabs in a window; but if the current tab is the *last* tab, it will *not* close the window. Instead, it has no effect. I've had to re-train myself to use <kbd>⇧⌘W</kbd> to close the window if there's only one tab left.
- If you've trained yourself to use <kbd>⌃V</kbd> in MacVim to do block-wise selection, then you'll have to re-train yourself to use [the alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426910/31897), <kbd>⌃Q</kbd> (or, now, <kbd>⌘Q</kbd>). Additionally, [you'll have to add](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12108/12095) `stty -ixon` in your shell's startup-script, as <kbd>⌃Q</kbd> is consumed by default to preform an archaic shell-control function (one with no modern usage.)

---

### Alternative <kbd>⌘W</kbd> behaviour

In addition to the above, I decided to further override <kbd>⌘W</kbd> as a universal ‘close this’ key, applicable to multiple applications.

Instead of mapping <kbd>⌘W</kbd> to ‘Close Tab,’ as above; I personally map that to <kbd>⇧⌘W</kbd> (to retain “immediately close this tab” semantics.) Then, in any given program, I map <kbd>⌃W</kbd> to some sort of close-save-quit functionality.

For instance, in my `.vimrc`:

```
noremap  <C-W>    :confirm quit<CR>
vnoremap <C-W>    <C-C>:confirm quit<CR>
inoremap <C-W>    <C-O>:confirm quit<CR>
```

… or my `.zshrc`:

```
function close_tab { exit }
zle -N close_tab_widget close_tab
bindkey           '' close_tab_widget
bindkey -M vicmd  '' close_tab_widget
```

With those two snippets in place, and your Terminal configured to ‘Close if shell exits cleanly,’ a series of <kbd>⌘W</kbd>s will first quit vim, and then close the shell entirely.

In addition, now additional on-exit functionality of programs can be preserved: for instance, `vim` will ask before quitting if files are unsaved (just like MacVim); and `zsh` will ask before quitting if there are background jobs.

---

*Postscript:* Not *directly* related to your question; but you should also check out ‘Ubiquitous Vim Mode’ in Karabiner. It's “a bit much” for me to use everyday, but it's a very cool idea, and surprisingly-well implemented.

Comment: Here's a Karabiner `private.xml` to exclude ⌘␣: https://github.com/tekezo/Files/blob/master/Karabiner/private.left_command_to_left_control_terminal/private.xml

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this applies, but `stty` uses ctrl-s to stop the terminal until restarted with ctrl-q. I'd be a bit leery about sending ctrl-s to a terminal.

Comment: I tried this and it did not seem to have any effect when I added it to mt .bashrc, a slightly modified version of what was indicated here http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-S_to_save_current_or_new_files